# Redirect to Google Captcha after an X amount of req/seconds is hit

Tags: google-cloud-armor

Currently we have an Cloud Armor protected backend. And this site is doing around 150 req/seconds accross all visitors. We would like to make an WAF rule when the amount of requests is for eg. 300 req/sec redirect vistitors to reCaptcha Enterprise.

The requests amount are based on the graphic from https://console.cloud.google.com/net-security/securitypolicies/adaptiveprotection?project=xxxxxx .

Is this possible?

If not I was thinking to create an Metric based alert, create a pub/sub event and call a Cloud Function to enable/disable a rule so that 0.0.0.0/0 are redirected to reCaptcha. Any toughts about this?

I checked the documentation but I could not find the info I needed. But maybe I overlooked it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible in a single rule motion as the ACTION value is either *redirect* or *rate limit* (throttle/ban). The ReCaptcha javascript would already have to be in your HTML page so the issue at hand is whether or not Cloud Armor will evaluate the assessment or not at a particular threshold level.

The rate limiting rule is just that- it will start to deny requests if the threshold limit is reached so putting the rate limit rule in your policy will limit access to high volume end users regardless if they are a bot or not and/or pass the ReCaptcha assessment.

You could create a trigger to update the Cloud Armor policy rule with a ReCaptcha evaluation rule but this rule is mutually exclusive to the rate limit rule. One way to generate the trigger is to create a preview rule for rate limiting and then have that fire an alert. Since it is a preview rule, it will never actually action anything, but you could use this to trigger your event to add the ReCaptcha rule into the policy. It takes about 2 minutes to update a Cloud Armor policy.

Cloud Armor rules process in a linear fashion so the first rule that matches, wins, and stops additional rules processing - it will never cascade down through the policy once a match has been determined.